# toString method in self-defined class using ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

I am using three classes in my program:

- `Term` class with variables coefficient and exponent, toString() method etc.
- `Polynome` class, using an ArrayList to store the different `Term` objects.
- `Main` class that runs the program.

Can I use the `toString` method of ArrayList in my Polynome class? I'm trying to, but I can't.

I need my polynome to output like this: [3x^2, 3x^1, 1x^0]

I am really confused, I'm calling the toString method of Term, using a for-loop to access each term separately.

My code:

```
public class Term {
    private int coëfficiënt;
    private int exponent;

    public Term(int coëfficiënt, int exponent) {
        this.coëfficiënt = coëfficiënt;
        this.exponent = exponent;
    }

    public int getCoef() {
        return coëfficiënt;
    }

    public int getExp() {
        return exponent;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return coëfficiënt + "x^" + exponent;
    }
}
```

Polynome class:

```
public class Polynoom {
    private ArrayList<Term> polynoom;

    public Polynoom() {
        polynoom = new ArrayList<Term>();
    }

    public void add(Term term) {
        polynoom.add(term);
    }

    public Term get(int i) {
        return polynoom.get(i);
    }

    public int size() {
        return polynoom.size();
    }

    public String toString() {
        // what should I write here?
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class opgave3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Polynoom polynoom1, polynoom2, sompolynoom;

        polynoom1 = new Polynoom();
        polynoom1.add(new Term(1, 2));
        polynoom1.add(new Term(3, 1));
        polynoom1.add(new Term(1, 0));

        polynoom2 = new Polynoom();
        polynoom2.add(new Term(-1, 3));
        polynoom2.add(new Term(2, 2));
        polynoom2.add(new Term(-5, 0));

        System.out.println("Tests: ");
        System.out.println(polynoom1.toString());
        for (int i = 0; i < polynoom1.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(polynoom1.get(i).toString());
        }
        System.out.println(polynoom1.get(0).toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to post your code.

Comment: "Can I use the toString method of ArrayList in my Polynome class?" yes, for more detailed answer explaining problems with your code we need to see it first.

Comment: To add more informations to your question use [edit] option (just saying since lack of `editor` badge suggests you never used it, so maybe you don't know about it).

Comment: Thank you all, makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: The quick answer, since you put your code up is to put

```
return polynoom.toString();
```

where you have indicated. Then in your Main class you can simply write

```
System.out.println(polynoom1);
```

to show the contents in the desired format.

As Tenner said, use the toString() method of your ArrayList to get the desired output. But also make sure your Term class has a useful toString method of its own:

```
public class Term {
    private int co, ex;

    public Term(int coeff, int exp) {
        co = coeff;
        ex = exp;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return co + "x^" + ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need to use your `ArrayList`'s `toString()` method as the results of    `Polynome`'s `toString()` method.

```
public class Polynome {
    public ArrayList<Term> terms;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (terms != null) {
            return terms.toString(); 
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `@Override toString()` to your `Term` & `Polynome` class.  The `Term` class `toString()` should return a string in the format of *coefficient*x^*exponent*.

Then have the `Polynome` class `toString()` return `yourArrayList.toString()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Polynome polynome = new Polynome();
    polynome.addTerm(3, 2);
    polynome.addTerm(3, 1);
    polynome.addTerm(1, 0);
    System.out.println(polynome);
}

public static class Term {
    private int coefficient;
    private int exponent;

    public Term(int c, int e) {
        coefficient = c;
        exponent = e;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return coefficient + "x^" + exponent;
    }
}

public static class Polynome {
    private List<Term> terms = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addTerm(int coefficient, int exponent) {
        terms.add(new Term(coefficient, exponent));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return terms.toString();
    }
}
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: `return terms.toString();` should work just as well as `return Arrays.toString(terms.toArray());`

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, you can ALWAYS use `toString()` on anything, even if it's a user defined class.  When you call the method, it calls the closest parent class's `toString()` method, which is guaranteed to be there as `Object` has one.  If you want to control the output of `toString()` called on your object, you must override it.  As it is, if you have an object with a member of type `ArrayList`, calling your object's `toString()` will include a ton of extra information that you probably don't want.  In order to get the output you want, you need to have the code given by @Tenner's answer, which is

```
public class Polynome {
    public ArrayList<Term> terms;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (terms != null) {
            return terms.toString(); 
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

But you also need to override `toString()` in the `Term` class, so that each term outputs in the form desired.  The reason this is required is that when you call `toString()` on an `ArrayList`, or any other container for that matter, it iterates through the container, calling each object's `toString()` in turn, adding whatever formatting the container class defines.  Ultimately, `Term`'s `toString()` will be called, and you can control that output by overriding it in the `Term` class.

As for the last part of the question, you need not call `Term`'s `toString()` directly, as calling the `toString()` method of the `ArrayList` will do this on its own.